# Emotion in Compassion Meditation

Tags: meditation, compassion

I have a very simple question. Sometimes, I visualize in compassion meditation without feeling anything for the whole session. Sometimes, I feel a lot of affect and start even crying.

**Should one focus on/have the emotional sensations in compassion meditation for it to be efficient, or is visualizing -- even without emotion -- enough?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "[Awareness Itself](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/thai/fuang/itself.html#med)", we read the advice given by Ajaan Fuang, as recorded by his student Thanissaro Bhikkhu:

> § A young nurse practiced meditation with Ajaan Fuang several days
>   running, and finally asked him one day, "Why wasn't today's session as
>   good as yesterday's?"
>
> He answered: "Meditating is like wearing clothes. Today you wear
>   white, tomorrow red, yellow, blue, whatever. You have to keep
>   changing. You can't wear the same set of clothes all the time. So
>   whatever color you're wearing, just be aware of it. Don't get
>   depressed or excited about it."
>
> § A few months later the same nurse was sitting in meditation when a
>   sense of peace and clarity in her mind became so intense that she felt
>   she would never have a bad mood infiltrate her mind again. But sure
>   enough, bad moods eventually came back as before. When she mentioned
>   this to Ajaan Fuang, he said, "Looking after the mind is like raising
>   a child. There will have to be bad days along with the good. If you
>   want only the good, you're in for trouble. So you have to play
>   neutral: Don't fall in with the good or the bad."
>
> § "When the meditation goes well, don't get excited. When it doesn't
>   go well, don't get depressed. Simply be observant to see why it's
>   good, why it's bad. If you can be observant like this, it won't be
>   long before your meditation becomes a skill."
>
> § A student came to complain to Ajaan Fuang that she had been
>   meditating for years, and still hadn't gotten anything out of it. His
>   immediate response: "You don't meditate to 'get' anything. You
>   meditate to let go."
>
> § "You should watch visions the same way you watch TV: Just watch it,
>   without getting pulled inside the tube."